# $f(x,y)=\frac12y^2e^{−x}$ if $ 0<y<x<∞$ Find $P(Y<1\mid X=3)$

Tags: probability

Let $(X,Y)$ be the probability density function:

$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} \dfrac{1}{2}y^2e^{-x} & \text{if } 0<y<x<\infty, \\[8pt] 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$

Find $P(Y<1\mid X=3)$

Which is $\dfrac{P(Y<1 \cap X=3)}{P(X=3)}$

I have read that probability at a particular point for a continuous distribution is $0$. So the denominator is $0$  right?

[Reference](https://prnt.sc/zaixpj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intended approach is probably to compute the [conditional density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution#Conditional_continuous_distributions) of $Y$ given $X=3$ using the formula $f_{Y \mid X=x}(y) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$ where $f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dy$, and then compute $P(Y < 1 \mid X=3)$ as $\int_{-\infty}^1 f_{Y \mid X=3}(y) \, dy$.

You've touched on an interesting technical point about conditioning on an event with zero probability. Using the usual definition of conditional probability fails because of division by zero. [This Wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Conditioning_on_an_event_of_probability_zero) discusses this a little bit with an approximation argument that works for joint densities, but is problematic more generally; see [regular conditional probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability) for the general way this is usually handled. But all this is probably out of scope of your class if this is an introductory class to probability; you are likely only expected to know how to handle the case with a joint density as discussed above.